# Safe access to member variables with sychronized keyword in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

When multiple threads can have access to a member variable I always use `synchronized` to make te access safe.

I used it in methods which access the member variable

```
public synchronized void foo()
{
  //do something with the member variable
}
```

or every access to the member is surrounded with `synchronized`

```
synchronized(member)
{
  //do something with the member here
}
```

I never use any other mechanism like semaphores and similar in multithreading applications to get safe access to member variables, I was wondering if I overlooked something and there is a serious reason why I should not do it that way? I used `synchronized` as it is very fast to use it, as I don't have to create any other object like semaphores.

Comment: `sychronized(member)` doesn't "protect" the member, whatever we mean by protection.

Comment: @biziclop It does if literally every access to the member is surrounded by such a clause.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, but so does surrounding every access of the member with `synchronized("foo") {}`. What I meant to say is that there's nothing special in the choice of monitor object, there's no connection between an object's "contents" and the monitor associated with it. And if OP believes there is, that's a problem.

Comment: The question is a bit too vague. Casually using synchronized in many places can lead to deadlocks because the synchronization order matters. If you have an List that you will add/remove modify. That should be fine, but maybe a synchronized list would be better. If it is a value that you want to modify, again probably won't deadlock, but you could use one of the atomic values.

Comment: @biziclop Yes I know that I have to surround every access to the member with synchronized(member) to actually protect the access to it but anyway good hint to clarify it in the question.

Comment: If you just want your data to be safely accessible from multiple threads, `synchronized` is usually the way to go.  It's when you are creating and managing threads that you may need finer grained control.

Comment: @Warren Dew Yes thats the case here, its just for accessing internal data from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other constructs exist to solve certain problems. They can

- improve performance
- avoid deadlocks
- enable higher-level concurrency abstractions that would otherwise require very coarse-grained locking (of course you could also call that "improve performance")

A simple example for improving performance is a read-write-lock where a data-structure is safe to use by multiple threads as long as they only read from it. Only writers will have to acquire a non-shared lock.

Copy-on-Write / Immutable data structures / Snapshotting can allow one part of the application to work on some slightly outdated set of data, e.g. for reporting, without any locking and thus without impeding progress of other parts of an application.

Sufficiently complex code where synchronized methods call other code that also uses locks may eventually lead to code paths where locks are not taken in the same order, which is a recipe for deadlocks. Optimistic schemes (either try-lock or read-modify-conditional-update-or-retry) may be able to handle such situations more gracefully by having an error path that can notify a different layer that it has to retry.